# Where was id_rsa.pub file created at?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I ran the following SSH commands to create my rsa key but I don't know where the file was created at

```
drlloyd@DIS-7L79KF1 ~/.ssh
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@gmail.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/f/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /f/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /f/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
I removed the rsa fingerprint
```

Where was the id_rsa.pub file created at?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Er, `~/.ssh`, or specifically in your case `/f/.ssh`?

If you're on Windows, look at `F:\.ssh`

Comment: Duh, I'm dumb. I didn't think that was the drive letter because no where during the installation or anything did I tell it to use drive F. That's weird.

Answer (score 10):

For me this file existed in c:/Users/Lee/.ssh

Lee

Answer (score 5):

id_rsa.pub is at /f/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Edit: Did not realize you were on Windows.  Type the following to get the contents of id_rsa.pub

```
cd /f/.ssh/
cat id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: @Brian: Not a troll, just a user that forgot to specify he's on Windows

Comment: @orip I was referring to Ransom posting the answer that anyone with a little wit would post. It was a compliment to him and not in any way a slight to OP. Oh, bother...

Comment: @brian I'm no troll. I didn't think that was the drive letter because no where during the installation or anything did I tell it to use drive F.

Comment: @guanome my comment was in no way attributed to you.

Comment: @brian I saw your second comment after my comment, no worries.

Comment: @guanome - it will use whatever $HOME is, as to how it determines $HOME I am not sure of the details

Comment: cat: id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory . This is what I got in my windows laptop